# math.sqrt domain error when square rooting a positive number

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am getting a domain error when square rooting a positive number. It originally was occurring in a complicated program but I was able to reproduce the bug as simply as doing the following:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16251.1002]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Adam>python
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(1.3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
>>>
```

I upgraded from version 3.6.1 to 3.6.2 to try to resolve the issue and restarted my computer but it is still occurring. Some numbers are working (1.2, 1.4) and some others are also not working (1.128).

The code I'm working on is working in Ubuntu but not in Win10 and this seems to be the issue stopping it from working.

Comment: If you want a workaround, use `1.3 ** (1/2)`

Comment: welcome to SO! best luck with that

Comment: @coldspeed True, perhaps a bit slower (speed is something of an issue on the program I'm working on) but I'm just so confounded as to why it is happening at all.

Comment: @Zev Are you building Python yourself? The `5fd33b5` looks like some HEAD-hash...

Comment: @Zev Does it occur for int values as well?

Comment: @MSeifert no, I installed from an exe downloaded today from python.org

Comment: @officialaimm seems to just be for floats

Comment: @MSeifert 5fd33b5 is the git or github hash of the commit delivered as 3.6.2.  It is the same for my 64-bit Windows install from python.org.

Comment: I do not see the problem on either installed 64bit 3.6.2 or built-from-repository debug 32bit 3.6.2+ .

Comment: Quick smoke-test: can you show the value of `math.__file__` please? Editing your question to add that would eliminate a particular class of issue (or reveal the problem, perhaps).

Comment: Does it still happen when you run the program in a terminal vs the python interpreter?

Comment: Do you have a file called math.py in that folder?  I was able to get it to work and I'm on python 2.4.3.  I was reproducing the issue since I was in a location that had a file named math.py, once I tried the directory above it I was able to get  math.sqrt(1.3) = 1.1401754250991381

Comment: @Ragxion That's what I wanted to test with checking `math.__file__`.

Comment: @rosuav and ragxion: It is a good thought but I don't have any files named math and it has the same issue with different directories. I like your idea of checking what math lib is being imported but math.__file__ tells me that math has no attribute file (maybe it is being statically linked in because it is a c library?). When I do help(math) all the normal functions are listed.

Comment: I posted ` If you are running 32-bit 3.6 on Windows, please test this` on python list.  So far, three people have reported so far that math.sqrt(1.3) works for them on 3.6.1 or .2 with 32 bit python (all on 64-bit windows). This suggests that the problem is likely local to one machine.

Comment: @Ragxion the problem originally occurred in a program and after doing debug I traced it down to this issue which I was able to replicate in the python interpreter. So, yes, the problem occurs on both.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks for checking. I did assume it was specific to my machine because it seems too major of an issue (not being able to sqrt several floats) to have been overlooked.

Comment: @Zev could you check `from ctypes import cdll;print(cdll.msvcrt);
print(cdll.load("msvcrt"))` please

Comment: Is the issue specific to `math.sqrt` or do you see the same results with other math library functions (for example, `math.exp`, `math.sin`)? One possibility here is that it's the literal-to-float conversion that's going wrong, before `math.sqrt` is even called. What do you see for `(1.3).hex()`, for example? (The result should be `'0x1.4cccccccccccdp+0'`.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson I'll have to experiment more but it seems specific to sqrt. math.exp(1.3) worked and I got the expected hex value.

Comment: @Liso 
>>> from ctypes import cdll;print(cdll.msvcrt); print(cdll.load("msvcrt"))
<CDLL 'msvcrt', handle 74ff0000 at 0x51c3390>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 418, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python36\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Comment: This seems like an unnecessary headache, have you tried uninstalling python and reinstalling it in that same or new directory?  That might be worth giving a try since we haven't seemed to pinpoint the issue yet.

Comment: @Zev pls this one too -> `import ctypes;msc = ctypes.windll.msvcrt;msc.sqrt.restype = ctypes.c_double;msc.sqrt.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double];msc.sqrt(1.3)` it directly call sqrt from msvcrt.dll and give me 1.140175425099138 on my win7 python3.6.2. So we could probably check if there is problem in msvcrt.dll on your machine.

Comment: @Liso, Python doesn't directly use msvcrt.dll. It's a private runtime used by Windows components such as advapi32.dll. Applications shouldn't link with msvcrt.dll directly. Also, stdcall (i.e. `ctypes.WinDLL`) is the wrong calling convention for the CRT. That won't work in 32-bit Python; it happens to work in 64-bit because cdecl and stdcall are the same in the x64 architecture. For Python 3.6 the C library to load is `ucrt = ctypes.CDLL('ucrtbase', use_errno=True)`, with the prototype `ucrt.sqrt.restype = ctypes.c_double;` `ucrt.sqrt.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double]`. Then call `ucrt.sqrt(1.3)`.

Comment: @Liso It is returning "nan" for 1.3 after following your instructions (and normal results for all int values and some floats. Let me know what that tells you. My plan is to uninstall and reinstall. I used workarounds (another computer) this time but will keep this thread posted if I get it working.

Comment: @Zev I am not very experienced windows user but maybe you could try sfc tool (see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/downloaded-windows-10-msvcrtdll-missing-message/87d48295-2969-4f62-88cd-7d0030946099?auth=1 )

Comment: @Liso Running that tool seems to have fixed it! Thanks! Feel free to submit it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

retro from comments:

1. try

```java
import ctypes
msc = ctypes.windll.msvcrt
msc.sqrt.restype = ctypes.c_double
msc.sqrt.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double]
msc.sqrt(1.3)
```

(It turned out that problem was in msvcrt.dll)

2. try sfc tool (see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/downloaded-windows-10-msvcrtdll-missing-message/87d48295-2969-4f62-88cd-7d0030946099?auth=1 )

   - Left click on Start button.
   - Right click on Command Prompt (Admin) option which will let you run 'Run as administrator’.
   - Command Prompt Window pops up.
   - Type:  SFC /SCANNOW and hit Enter.